# Getting custom element using puppeteer and then do click action

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I've created a custom attribute called *data-testId* and I am trying to reach to using puppeteer and then do a click action, but for some reason, I'm unable to get this element and facing with errors.
I've tried these 2 options:

```
const element = await page.$('[data-testId="testid-button-refresh"]');
await page.click(element, { clickCount: 1 });
```

and this:

```
const refreshButton = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
return document.querySelector('[data-testId=testid-button-refresh]').value;
});
await page.click(element, { clickCount: 1 });
```

On them both I am getting this error:

> ```
> JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created!
> ```

What I am doing wrong? and what does it means this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `element` you've created an [ElementHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-class-elementhandle) which can be clicked with [`elementHandle.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions) and not with `page.click`.

This should work:

```js
const element = await page.$('[data-testId="testid-button-refresh"]') // this is an ElementHandle
await element.click({ clickCount: 1 })
```

Or you can still use [`page.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pageclickselector-options), but to keep the click in the same context you should use the selector, and not the ElementHandle as the first argument:

```js
await page.click('[data-testId="testid-button-refresh"]', { clickCount: 1 })
```

Comment: You are right, this was the issue for me. I kept doing the click with page and not with the element - probably missed it.